# How to cache 404 responses in django?

Tags: django, caching

I use **django** `FileBasedCache` backend. By default it caches only `200` responses and documentation doesn't mention any settings parameter that help specify which status code to cache.

How to customize it to cache 404 responses?

Comment: Django mixes together the concepts of a local cache and an HTTP cache, so you should clarify what you mean. Specifically, are you crafting custom 404 responses that you want to cache locally, or are you just wanting to set the appropriate cache headers so that clients will cache your 404 responses?

Comment: I am talking about HTTP server cache. I need to cache it because it will be a big performance boost since it takes time for the server to figure out if he must return 404.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the cache *backend* implementation. It's the logic of caching itself implemented by the cache middleware classes, specifically `UpdateCacheMiddleware`. There are no settings or parameters to customise that; it is hardcoded: [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/34d1905712d33e72c76b3a55a4fc24abbd11be6c/django/middleware/cache.py#L106).

So, to change that, you'll need to roll out your custom middleware implementation.

Comment: Thanks for theses informations, any more guidlines how to " roll out my custom middleware implementation" because the only line I need to change is from `==200` to `in [200, 404]`

Comment: Yes, as the most straightforward solution, you could just edit that line and the line above: [L81](https://github.com/django/django/blob/34d1905712d33e72c76b3a55a4fc24abbd11be6c/django/middleware/cache.py#L81)

Comment: Is there a way to do it whithout redefining the whole Class ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that modular; all the logic is implemented inside the `process_response` method. Theoretically, you could inherit from `UpdateCacheMiddleware` and override just the `process_response` method, but it is not worth it – it will save you just a couple of lines. So I would create a new standalone class with those few lines changed.